# What is the simplest way to have text be shown at full font-size inside an input container?

Tags: css

I have a table with a label in column 1 and an input field in column 2.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="title" value="My Title" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The input field text appears smaller than the label text. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ch3wmd2/1/). I assume this is because the input field takes space which seems to cause the input text to be smaller to fit within the remaining space?

What I want is for the input text to always be the same font size as the label text, expanding the row height if needed to accommodate. How to do this generically on table rows with various input fields?

Comment: Set `font-size` on the `input` elements to match the `font-size` used on the label? You set the `font-size` on `:root` in your fiddle, so do the same for `input`. You could probably use `font-size: inherit;`.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I tried font-inherit but it doesn't seem to be exactly the same size. https://jsfiddle.net/txbnz8av/4/

Comment: Please post your Fiddle as a running [reprex] in your question to keep question and example in the same place. Fiddles often get deleted. Failing to do so is usually the main reason people on SO downvote a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use CSS to set font properties, like `font`,`font-family`, `font-size`, `color`, etc. specifically or have those properties `inherit` the values set by a (ancestor) parent element. Essentially like you did in your Fiddle.

Because:

Most, if not all HTML `<input type="...">` elements, as well as a few others like `<select>` and `<option>`, `<label>` have default markup values set by the User Agent (browser) to make them closely resemble the respective widgets used by the Operating System of your device (PC/smartphone) outside the browser.

Think of default:

- font settings.
- graphics like colors, border and shadows.
- behavior like dropdown or open/close Operating System modal windows (e.g. file selection modal).

You can easily override fonts and graphics in your CSS, but changing behavior often requires the introduction of Javascript to 'catch' default actions and replace them with your own (usually some 'Observer' or 'eventlistener'). A next step in the wondrous world of web design...

Answer (score 0):

Just add font-size property to the input element with the same size of your font.
And you are good to go

```css
:root {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 16px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#input1 {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Title</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="title" value="My Title" id="input1" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Sagar, welcome to SO! While perfectly legal, your solution is somewhat ill advised as you should never override the browsers' user default font size settings with an *absolute length unit* for `:root font-size`. This way you will prohibit the user from changing the default font settings, which they may need for visibility reasons. A simple `input { font-size: 1em }` will suffice as it will inherit whatever font size its parent element has.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I put font-size:inherit on input but to my eye they're still not the same. https://jsfiddle.net/txbnz8av/4/

Comment: @mr.b, just checked your Fiddle: you need to add `font-family: inherit` too as by default some system font is used for `input`...

Comment: Thanks Rene, that works and I'm starting to understand how this all works. Do you want to submit an answer I can accept?